# form_validation in codeigniter gives "Required " Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im currently working on a codeigniter project and im trying to use the form_validation library and im having a small problem..

ive created a function that validates some fields.
ex.

```
public function validate_employee_data($data) {
    var_dump("EMPLOYEE");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($data['firstname'], 'First Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($data['lastname'], 'Last Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($data['nickname'], 'Nick Name', 'trequired');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($data['email'], 'Email Address', 'required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($data['contact_no'], 'Contact Number', 'required|min_length[11]|max_length[12]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($data['group_tags'], 'Group Tags', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        echo validation_errors();
    }
    else {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

ive tried to var_dump the $data and it's not empty however the validation still throws "(This) Field is Required", im a bit confused on what is the reason why this error keeps on showing up.

thanks in advance guys..

Comment: Can you post the content of `var_dump($data)` and `validation_errors()`

Comment: Ive solved it. it must be the name of the field specified in the FORM.

Comment: nickname field, trequired? It is not required?

Answer (score 1):

Answer: The form validation must only be used with the forms field names not the variable itself.

Comment: you should edit your first post to show the answer, can be useful for someone

Answer (score 1):

nickname field, trequired? It is not required?

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules($data['nickname'], 'Nick Name', 'trequired');
```

to

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules($data['nickname'], 'Nick Name', 'required');
```

**or maybe your form fields to match the validation, verify that too**

Answer (score 1):

first of all , please check form validation libraries to load in autoload or your function uppar side, if yes so please ignore it.

Please Use this code

```
public function validate_employee_data($data) {
    var_dump("EMPLOYEE");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nickname', 'Nick Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact_no', 'Contact Number', 'required|min_length[11]|max_length[12]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('group_tags', 'Group Tags', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        echo validation_errors();
    }
    else {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Ref. for this answer : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html